# Showcaseview on girdview item android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, showcaseview

I have created an app and want to show some first time user bubbles. I am using showcaseview 
https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

How do i set it on the first element of the gridview ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewTarget as follows:

Your activity should implement OnShowcaseEventListener.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            View targetView = gridview.getChildAt(0);
            ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(targetView);
            ShowcaseView sv  = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this, true)
                .setTarget(target)
                .setContentTitle("YOUR MESSAGE")
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                .setShowcaseEventListener(this)
                .build();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Basically you are passing the required view to the ViewTarget. You can highlight other child also. Just remember to execute the code only after the views ahve been inflated otherwise it might throw exception.
See if it works for you.

Comment: I used this code in onviewcreated and it threw  nullpointer exception at gridview.getChildAt(0);. This solution wont work

Comment: I have already mentioned. Use this code when the child is inflated. What you can do is use this code inside a handler with postDelayed. I will update the answer.

Comment: can you share a snippet of code to explain better? Should i call this inside an adapter?

Comment: By using handler you are delaying the code to be executed by 5 secs.

Comment: Yes you can try it inside adapter also when the first child is being inflated.